# How to reduce CPU usage of my python script that performs SQL queries against Postgresql db

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a python script that is getting killed by the kernel after reaching 99% CPU utilization. The python is performing SQL queries against a postgresql db and appending the results to a single JSON file. The issue occurs when I reach query 150 and the CPU utilization goes to 99+% and then the kernel kills the script. I would like this script to perform all of the sql queries error free. How can I improve my code so this doesn't happen? I would greatly appreciate your help!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)


import re
import sys
import json
import pprint
import time

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

# DELAY = 0


def connect_to_db():
    start = 0
    offset = 10
    psycopg2(...) as conn:
    flag = True
    while flag:
        filepath = 'forager.txt'
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            unique_domains = ''
            try:
                conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.itersize = 10000
                for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                    print(domain_name)
                    domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                    cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_keySize(c.certificate), x509_publicKeyMD5(c.certificate), x509_publicKey(c.certificate), x509_rsaModulus(c.certificate), x509_serialNumber(c.certificate), x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_subjectName(c.certificate), x509_name(c.certificate), x509_name_print(c.certificate), x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_subjectKeyIdentifier(c.certificate), x509_extKeyUsages(c.certificate), x509_certPolicies(c.certificate), x509_canIssueCerts(c.certificate), x509_getPathLenConstraint(c.certificate), x509_altNames(c.certificate), x509_altNames_raw(c.certificate), x509_cRLDistributionPoints(c.certificate), x509_authorityInfoAccess(c.certificate), x509_print(c.certificate), x509_anyNamesWithNULs(c.certificate), x509_extensions(c.certificate), x509_tbscert_strip_ct_ext(c.certificate), x509_hasROCAFingerprint(c.certificate)
                    FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                    c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                    lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                # query db with start and offset
                    unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
                    if not unique_domains:
                        flag = False
                    else:
                        # do processing with your data

                        pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                        outfilepath = "crtsh2" + ".json"
                        with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                                outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                        offset += limit


            except Exception as error:
                print(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: Killing a process for reasonable CPU usage is not normal. Sounds like some over-protective settings. If you can't change them, add some short `time.sleep()` calls.

Comment: Could you try writing to your text files in smaller chunks perhaps? What I mean is, rather than holding both files open, open the file, write to it, close it, next query, open close etc...

Comment: You are also connecting to the database loads of times by the looks of things, surely you only want to connect before the loop, and disconnect after the final loop?

Comment: @KlausD. so you are saying to put time.sleep() at the bottom of my code before I can except, correct?

Comment: @Swift have the key there, also maybe you can do it in just one query, or in some kind of batch to avoid repeating queries.

Comment: I'm not sure `time.sleep()` would be appropriate, surely this will just delay how long it's takes for the kernel to kill is process?

Comment: @Swift thanks for your help! Could you provide me an example. I just did a quick google search and I saw that people are saying that by using "with open" you don't have to worry about opening and closing the file, as it will close when the code is out of scope. Is this true?

Comment: @Netwave Thank you for the advice! Can you please provide me an example of how to do it in just one query.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct, I would say in most cases it's best practice to use `with` to open files, you can even use it with the queries but I would need to open up Idle and give it a test run.

Comment: I believe you want `with psycopg2(...) as conn:`

Comment: @Swift Where should I put that statement?

Comment: For the files you would do `with open(filename, 'rt') as fileA:`

Comment: Put that psycopg2 statement just before Flag = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177670/discussion-between-swift-and-bedford).

Answer (score 0):

```
def connect_to_db():
    start = 0
    offset = 10
    flag = True

    while flag:
        filepath = 'forager.txt'
        print('am i stuck')
        with open(filepath, "at+") as fp, open(outfilepath, "wt+") as outfile:
            unique_domains = ''
            try:
                #conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))


                for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                    print(domain_name)
                    domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()
                    with psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST)) as conn:
                        cursor = conn.cursor()
                        cursor.itersize = 10000
                        cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_keySize(c.certificate), x509_publicKeyMD5(c.certificate), x509_publicKey(c.certificate), x509_rsaModulus(c.certificate), x509_serialNumber(c.certificate), x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_subjectName(c.certificate), x509_name(c.certificate), x509_name_print(c.certificate), x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_subjectKeyIdentifier(c.certificate), x509_extKeyUsages(c.certificate), x509_certPolicies(c.certificate), x509_canIssueCerts(c.certificate), x509_getPathLenConstraint(c.certificate), x509_altNames(c.certificate), x509_altNames_raw(c.certificate), x509_cRLDistributionPoints(c.certificate), x509_authorityInfoAccess(c.certificate), x509_print(c.certificate), x509_anyNamesWithNULs(c.certificate), x509_extensions(c.certificate), x509_tbscert_strip_ct_ext(c.certificate), x509_hasROCAFingerprint(c.certificate)
                        FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                        c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                        lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                # query db with start and offset
                    unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
                    if not unique_domains:
                        flag = False
                    else:
                        # do processing with your data

                        pprint.pprint(unique_domains)


                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                        offset += limit


            except Exception as error:
                print(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Give that a whirl and let me know if it improves anything, I will revise the answer if it doesnt do much.

Comment: Please add a description of you approach! Code only answers are less helpful to others.

Comment: @KlausD. My approach is to perform a sql query on each of the domains from my .txt file and write the result to a .json file using a loop. My goal of using a loop is to limit the amount of RAM I'm using for each query.

Comment: @KlausD. Im speaking with him directly in discussion about it. I will add it after for the purpose that you mentioned.